# Modifying style of parent div through css class in child div

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, slickgrid

I am using `slick grid`. Which applies `slick-cell` class on each cell in the grid. On one of cell I have added a another `div` and a class by name `red-bg`. See the below image for more information.

[image]

See the below image for more info on slick-cell class[image]

**Problem**: `slick-cell` class is adding `padding` to the cell. How can I though `red-bg` class, force to over-write style in slick-cell class. I want to over-write `padding` class.

Answer (score 0):

```
padding-top : 3px !important
```

padding : 0px in red class will overwrites

important overwrite other css

Comment: I want to remove padding and margin from the cell. How will using `padding-top : 3px !important` will help ?

Comment: red-bg{
  padding:0px;
}

Answer (score 0):

Put simply, you can't. CSS cascades from Parent to Child. You cannot target the parent from the child only the opposite way around or sibling to sibling.

A hack would be to negate the parent's padding on `red-bg` by putting a minus margin on `red-bg`. If `slick-cell` has `padding-top: 10px` you could theoretically do:

```
.red-bg {
    margin-top: -10px;
}
```

This becomes slightly more complicated if `slick-cell` has padding all around